# How can I troubleshoot a "VPN connection failed"?

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm trying to use [Hola](https://hola.org/)'s full VPN feature. In their setup guide they give instructions only for Windows and Android, but I should be able to use that info on Linux as well, i.e. VPN server, username and password.
Unfortunately, after setting up my VPN connection in the network manager, the connection fails. 
Here's a syslog output:

```
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 8796
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]: <info> VPN connection 'VPN connection 1' (Connect) reply received.
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pppd[8800]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pppd[8800]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pppd[8800]: Using interface ppp0
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pppd[8800]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/8
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pptp[8803]: nm-pptp-service-8796 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Sep 21 19:14:55 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pptp[8818]: nm-pptp-service-8796 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Sep 21 19:14:56 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pptp[8818]: nm-pptp-service-8796 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Sep 21 19:14:56 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pptp[8818]: nm-pptp-service-8796 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Sep 21 19:14:56 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pptp[8818]: nm-pptp-service-8796 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pptp[8818]: nm-pptp-service-8796 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pptp[8818]: nm-pptp-service-8796 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 47232).
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pppd[8800]: MS-CHAP authentication failed: 
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pppd[8800]: CHAP authentication failed
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pppd[8800]: Connection terminated.
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pptp[8818]: nm-pptp-service-8796 log[pptp_read_some:pptp_ctrl.c:544]: read returned zero, peer has closed
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pptp[8818]: nm-pptp-service-8796 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:258]: Closing connection (shutdown)
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pptp[8818]: nm-pptp-service-8796 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pptp[8818]: nm-pptp-service-8796 log[pptp_read_some:pptp_ctrl.c:544]: read returned zero, peer has closed
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pptp[8818]: nm-pptp-service-8796 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 pppd[8800]: Exit.
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]: <info> Policy set 'TNCAPC8C720' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Sep 21 19:14:57 giulio-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[1075]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
```

Can anyone tell me if there's anything wrong there or walk me through the setup?

**Note**: I had no problems establishing a connection on my Android tablet.